# Getting Focal Stastics to ignore NoData using ArcPy with Multiband Raster

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, focal-statistics

In ArcPy, I am running the [Focal Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm) tool to calculate the mean value of a raster within a 20 pixel buffer. I would like to ignore no data so that a value can be calculated even in locations where no data is available in the input raster. To do this, I run:

```
result = arcpy.sa.FocalStatistics(in_raster = r"in_raster.tif", neighborhood = "Circle 20 CELL", statistics_type = "MEAN", ignore_nodata = "DATA")

result.save(r"out_raster.tif")
```

However, the output result does not ignore the no data values:

[image]

The results are the same whether I set `ignore_nodata = "DATA"` or `ignore_nodata = "NODATA"`. I've also tried setting the parameter to `True` and `False` and the result it always the same.

How can I get Focal Stastics to ignore NoData in ArcPy so that results are calculated in the red hatched region?

Comment: This question specifically is related to ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this input raster has two bands. I was able to produce the output I was looking for by first creating a copy of the raster containing only the band of interest. When I ran the above code on the single-band version of the raster, the results were as expected, with the mean in the buffer being calculated using any cells within the specified distance:

[image]